# Send message on FB messenger when an order status is updated on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, woocommerce

Users can log-in via facebook to our eshop. When an order made by the user, a message must be sended to him on his facebook messanger app. For this task i need a "psid" from facebook api but i cant find how to get it. Can i generate this psid from the initial login he did on my eshop via facebook? By the way the is eshop is using woocommerce

Comment: The messenger API is for communication between a Facebook page and a user, not really made to send them messages from arbitrary sources to begin with. And for the most part, you are limited to _replying_ to users messaging you first - you can not send just any arbitrary number of messages you’d like. You _get_ the PSID, when they interact with a chatbot you have implemented on your FB page, and they start communicating with that.

Comment: thanks for your reply! that is what i keep telling my boss but the problem is that there is a quite big company that does exactly that and now he wants us to replicate it. I dont have a clue on how this company achieved that functionality though

Comment: Facebook has a couple of different scenarios, of when exactly you are allowed to send what. You’ll have to dive deeper into the documentation for details. (That a _really_ “big” company made some kind of special deal with Facebook, that allows them to do stuff other normal 3rd-party apps can’t, is also always a possibility though.)

Comment: Message Tags could be what you are looking for for these kinds of updates, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags#supported_tags - `POST_PURCHASE_UPDATE, Notify the user of an update on a recent purchase.` might fit.